# How to retrieve string after @ character and before space using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to programming. I would like to retrieve the string after an `@` character and before the next <kbd>space</kbd> entered by a user in an input field. For example take something like this:

> somestring @user enters

I would like to extract the string "user" here.

I have an input field and user entered input is stored in text state. Then whenever user enters @ in the input field i want to display a dropdown with the list of users. Now, when the user enters anything after the @ character I want to filter the users based on that string.

Currently this text state contains the entire user input.

Now when I filter the users list based on the text state it returns an empty array, because I'm filtering on the entire string.

Below is the code I have written to try and solve the problem:

```
class UserMention extends react.PureComponent {
    state = {
        text='',
        user_mention=false,
    };

    user_list = [
        {name: 'user1'},
        {name: 'first_user'},
        {name: 'second_user'},
    ];

    handle_input_change = (event) => {
        let user_mention;
        if (event.target.value.endsWith('@')) {
            user_mention = true;
        } else {
            user_mention = false;
        }

        this.setState({
            is_user_mention: is_user_mention,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
     }  

     render = () => {
         return {
             <input
                  required
                  name="text"
                  value={this.state.text}
                  onChange={this.handle_input_change}
                  type="text"/>
              {this.state.user_mention &&
                  <div>
                      {this.user_list.filter(user => 
                          user.user_name.indexOf(this.state.new_comment) 
                          !== -1).map((user,index) => (
                              <div key={index}>{user.name}
                              </div>
                          )) 
                       }
                   </div>
               }
           );};}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure I understand. What is the expected result for the string `hello @world`?

Comment: Use `split('@')`. This will give you the text before and after the @

Comment: thanks should get "world". if there are multiple occurences of @ say like in string "@user1 enters some text to @user2" then the last occurence of @ so the resulting string would be "user2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to find the last index of @ in the string, and get a [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) from that index onward. Then, you can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a space to extract just the user:

```js
const getUser = s => s.includes('@') && s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('@') + 1).split(' ')[0]

const log = console.log
log(getUser('@user1'))
log(getUser("@user1 enters some text to @user2"))
log(getUser('@user1 enters text @user3 more'))
log(getUser('@@@@user4'))
log(getUser('no at sign'))
```

Comment: What if the string is '@user1 enters text @user2 more'?

Comment: Nice one-liner, always love the simplicity of some solutions.

Comment: @rrd Yeah, it seems much cleaner when written in one line :)

Comment: this works but if user enters just string "hello" it gives hello as output.

Comment: Ah okay, one second. @stackoverflow_user check my edit now.

Comment: @Kobe how can i find all occurrence of string after @ like '@user1' and '@user2'

Comment: @Maul Just use a regular expression